# HTML Email - How do I get my 2 row, 4 column table to render properly Outlook 2007 - 2016

Tags: html, email, html-table, outlook

I am having trouble with a displaying a table in Outlook 2007 - 2016 for Windows (looks fine for Mac and in Browsers)

It should be centered, but Outlook is displaying it aligned to the left, and pretty much all the formatting is wrong.

I have attached images below of how it looks in the Browser (which is correct) and also what it looks like in Outlook (which looks awful)

Any advise? I have provided my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Untitled</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <table height="100px" width="550px" cellspacing="20px "style=" font-style:normal; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size: 10.53pt; background-color: #e6e6e6; margin:auto;">

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <table style="width:100%;">
                            <tr height="30px">
                                <td width="50px" style="text-align: center;">Login:</td>
                                <td width="200px" style="text-align: center; background-color: #fff; color: #7e7e7e;">###</td>
                                <td width="75px" style="text-align: center;">Password:</td>
                                <td width="200px" style="text-align: center; background-color: #fff; color: #7e7e7e;">###</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <table style="width:100%;">
                            <tr height="30px">
                                <td></td>
                                <td bgcolor="#9f1b32" style="width:200px; text-align: center; color: #fff; text-decoration:none;font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">RENEW NOW ></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </body>
    </html>
```

[Screenshot Previews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhioF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login:
              ###
              Password:
              ###
            
          
        
      
      
        
          
            
              
              RENEW NOW >

[Browser and Outlook comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyy4c.png)

Comment: I've copied your code and code the fonts to pull through, but still cannot get the table aligned to center of the page, or change the height of the grey table. It will do it for me in the browser but not outlook.  style="margin:auto; text-align: center; height: 136px;" within the outer <table> all seem to have no effect, any more suggestions

Comment: what are you using to test this?

Comment: Litmus. I am doing previews for Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016

Comment: wait wait, If you want the table aligned in the center just add in the table tag `align="center"` and for the height you need to add `<tr height="#">` check this (https://fiddle.jshell.net/5349ut3q/).

Comment: Using align="center" helps a little bit but still doesn't align the table fully in the middle. It's hard for me to show whats it's doing as I can't attach an image on here.. and if you just put the code above in a text editor and test it in a browser it looks fine.

Comment: I'm using litmus and tested the outlook 2010 and 2013 but 2016 is not available at the moment. anyway you can alway add new images the original post when you choose edit.

Comment: Hi Adam. I've uploaded a new screen shot to my original post and called it Screenshot Previews. I can't paste my entire code in here as it's not properly indented (i.e. with 4 spaces) so StackOverflow doesn't like it, and it will take me ages to go through and sort it out. (I'm tweaking a template someone else made for a previous project you see so it's a bit awkward). Any suggestions from the latest screenshot provided would be appreciated, if not I'll go back to the drawing board. thanks.

Comment: Hi Adam, in the end I just completely re-wrote all the code. The template I was using had some awful code in and loads of bloat so that probably didn't help. I have now finally got my table to center align.. however I am still having one issue. I can't get the correct padding at the top and bottom of my table in Outlook. Looks fine in the browser however Outlook displays hardly any padding. I will re post my updated code above and upload a new screenshot. Do you think I need to use an IF MSO rule somewhere?

Comment: I was going to suggest that to you, rewrite your code section by section and start from scratch. If my answer for centering the table worked please **accept** it and provide a link for the new code in codepen.io and will see whats going on.

Comment: so where you want to add the padding? and you don't need `;` in `<tr width="100%" height="100px" **;**>` . I personally prefer to remove any comments form emails as well you have a lot there.